# Username and password option is no longer visible in geoserver gui page

Tags: tomcat, geoserver

Post installing ssl for nginx. geo server is broken. I am not able to view any login information in geoserver
Its linux machine

I have check and compare the server.xml file for tomcat and set the data directory as well for geoserver.

Comment: Please make this about _programming_ to be on-topic ([help/on-topic]) and inspect all of your tags' descriptions when you tag a question. I'm removing 3 of the 5 that you used - if you add them again, please give us a reason (within the question). [ask]

Comment: did you correctly set the proxy_url in the GeoServer global settings? usually practice is to not log in to the GUI through your proxy to avoid this issue

Comment: This is resolve, as i have to path correct env variable path for geo server. Thank you.